# Can we arrange {1,...,9} in 3×3 grid so the set of products of rows equals the set of products of columns?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I find a interesting question of Prmo mock and Promys 2020

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is it possible to arrange $\{1,…,n^2\}$ in an $n\times n$ grid so that the set of products of columns equals the set of products of rows?

I can find solution for $3\times 3$ or $4\times 4$ but unable to generalize for  $n\times n$.

> The question has been answered by Rob Pratt but I am unable to understand his solution .

Can anyone please help me in this question

Comment: @JosephVanName sir , is there proof of this , pls share

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! This is a question for professional mathematicians to ask questions about their research, as is explained in the [help centre](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic). Maths Olympiad problems are almost certainly off topic here, but you could try asking on [Maths Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn i didn't knew sorry

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution of the Promys 2020 problem, following RobPratt and Mike Earnest at [Can we arrange $\{1,...,16\}$ in $4\times 4$-grid so {products of rows} = {products of columns}?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518460).

**Theorem.**  For $n\in\{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10\}$ one can arrange $\{1,\dotsc,n^2\}$ in an $n\times n$ grid so that the set of products of columns equals the set of products of rows. For $n\notin\{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10\}$ there is no such arrangement.

**Proof.** For $n\in\{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10\}$, see the [constructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518847) of RobPratt. For $n=2$ it is easy to check by hand there there is no arrangement. Now assume that $n=9$ or $n\geq 11$. Then, following Mike Earnest's [great idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636794), it suffices to show that $\pi(n^2)-\pi(n^2/2)>n$. For $n\in\{9,11,12,13,14,15,16\}$ we can verify this by hand. For $n\geq 17$ the required inequality follows from Corollary 3 in Rosser–Schoenfeld: Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers. Indeed, by this theorem we have that
$$\pi(n^2)-\pi(n^2/2)>\frac{(3/10)n^2}{\log(n^2/2)}>n,\qquad n\geq 17.$$